# Group actions on product varieties by diagonal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, complex-geometry, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be two varieties, and $G$ be a group together with actions on $X$ and $Y$. Moreover, we assume the action on $X$ is free. I would like to know if the following statement is true:

> There is always an isomorphism $(X \times Y)/ G \simeq X/G \times Y$, where $G$ acts on $X\times Y$ by diagonal.

I guess this is not true in general, as it seems not easy to define a morphism between them. However, I don't have a counter-example in mind. It would be nice if there are some general facts about this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no such an isomorphism. Here an example:
Let $X=Y=C$ be a  Riemann surface of genus $g(C)=3$, and
$G\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (there do exist Riemann surfaces with such an action, by the Riemann existence theorem).

By Künneth formula (since G acts freely on $C$  and diagonal on $C\times C$) you have $$
\begin{array}{l}H^0((C\times C)/G, \Omega^1)&=& H^0((C\times C), \Omega^1)^G= 
H^0(C, \Omega^1)^G \oplus H^0(C, \Omega^1)^G \\&=& H^0(C/G, \Omega^1)\oplus H^0(C/G, \Omega^1)\end{array}$$
In particular $q((C\times C)/G)= \dim H^0((C\times C)/G, \Omega^1)=2\cdot g(C/G)=2\cdot 2$ (by the Hurwitz formula).

Arguing in the same way you see that $q(C/G \times C)= \dim H^0(C/G\times C, \Omega^1)= 2+ 3\neq 4$.

Comment: Many thanks! A minor mistake: in your last sentence, it should be $2+3$, instead of $2 \cdot 3$.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I corrected it!